# Grails: What is the best way to execute two consecutive transactions that both modify the same object?

Tags: hibernate, grails, transactions

In my service there are resources that are reserved by users.
When user ends using/reserving a resource, checkout "controller method" is called.
In that method 3 things should happen, ideally. They are:
1. Resource is freed.
2. A remote payment service is called to charge user based on the amount the resource was used.
3. It is marked to Reservation object that it is paid.

Of these 3 steps, step 1 should happen always, and steps 2 and 3 only together.

My question is how to handle this ideally in code?
(Here, reservation objects object contains the information about a resources' reservation. If a reservation's use is started but not ended, then it is reserving the referenced resource.)
A: Can/should I share the reservation object between transactions? Or,
B: Should I "get" the reservation object separately in each transaction?
C: Does it have a bad smell to first get the reservation object outside of all transactions?
D: I'm now using Grails 2.4.4. Would your answer differ depending on the Grails version? Should I upgrade to a newer version?

Here is the example in code (where I get the reservation object only once).
(Of course, the transactions could occur in a service, but it was easier to demonstrate this using withNewTransaction approach.).
Is this a good way, or how should the code below be changed?

```
/*Domain class*/
class Reservation {
    Resource resource;
    Date useStarted;
    Date useEnded;
    Boolean charged;
}


class ReservationController {

    def nonTransactionalPaymentService

    def checkout(){
        def reservationId = params.reservationId as Long

        def reservation = Reservation.get(reservationId )
        Reservation.withNewTransaction {
            // reservation = Reservation.get(reservationId ) ??
            reservation.useEnded = new Date()
            reservation.save(failOnError: true)
        }
        Reservation.withNewTransaction {
            // reservation = Reservation.get(reservationId ) ??
            nonTransactionalPaymentService.charge(reservation)
            reservation.charged = true
            reservation.save(failOnError: true) // I'm screwed if this fails
        }
        // rendering code here
    }
 }
```

The reason why I am asking this is because there are 2 phenomena in my code that I have not yet been able to get rid off completely:
1. Strange exceptions such as: "Connection has been abandoned PooledConnection".
2. When getting an object, the changes of the previous transactions are not visible right away.

Answer (score 0):

I have found there is a difference between:

```
def reservation = Reservation.get(reservationId )
Reservation.withNewTransaction {
 ..
}
Reservation.withNewTransaction {
..
}
```

and

```
Reservation.withNewTransaction {
   def reservation = Reservation.get(reservationId )
    // reservation = Reservation.get(reservationId ) ??
    reservation.useEnded = new Date()
    reservation.save(failOnError: true)
}
Reservation.withNewTransaction {
   def reservation = Reservation.get(reservationId )
    // reservation = Reservation.get(reservationId ) ??
    nonTransactionalPaymentService.charge(reservation)
    reservation.charged = true
    reservation.save(failOnError: true) // I'm screwed if this fails
}
```

Meaning when you recall - reget the object within the new transaction you are in effect then picking up the latest changes.

There is also minor changes between `.read` `.get` and if transaction is disabled in overall service or not. Take a look at the [queuekit](https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-queuekit-plugin) plugin lots of newTransaction stuff going on in there to try to pick out latest updates at any one time.